# How to track Gmail user's Online_Status?

Tags: android, gmail, contacts, status

Hi i'm making an app which need to get user's gmail account contact list and online_status. I have searched the net finally i got list of all contacts related to my account from this code

```
Cursor emailCur = cr.query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.
                                                  Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", 
                                                  new String[]{_id}, null);         
while (emailCur.moveToNext()) { 

   String email = emailCur.getString(
                emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));          
   String emailType = emailCur.getString(
   emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE)); 

} 
emailCur.close();
```

Now, I want to get the online status of those contact's like **( Available, Busy, Idele, Unavailable )**..
How can i do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String status=ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_PRESENCE;
```

this would give the status.

Contact IM presence status. The values are:

- OFFLINE 0
- INVISIBLE 1
- AWAY 2
- IDLE 3
- DO_NOT_DISTURB 4
- AVAILABLE 5